# Multiple Count Downs inside ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, countdown, simplecursoradapter

i am trying to solve problem for 2 days now and without success. I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to load messages to ListView. Every ListView row need to have counter. I have problem with counter,and i can't make it work inside SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder. Here is my code:

```
 public class ChatActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    private ListView chatScreen;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        onNewIntent(getIntent());

        chatScreen = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        chatScreen.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_chat_message,
                null,
                new String[]{DataProvider.COL_MSG, DataProvider.COL_AT},
                new int[]{R.id.chat_message, R.id.chat_date},
                0);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();

                TextView text = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.chat_counter);
                int position = chatScreen.getPositionForView(text);

                text.setText("60");
                text.setTag(position);

                final Handler mClockHandler = new Handler();
                mUpdateClockTask clockTask = new mUpdateClockTask(text, text.getTag().toString());
                mClockHandler.post(clockTask);

                switch(view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.chat_message:

                        LinearLayout chatMessage = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.chatSingleMessage);

                        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_FROM)) == null) {
                            root.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                            root.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
                            chatMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cloud_bubble_green);
                        } else {
                            root.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                            root.setPadding(10, 10, 50, 10);
                            chatMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cloud_bubble_blue);
                        }
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        chatScreen.setAdapter(adapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        chatScreen.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        final EmojiconEditText emojiconEditText = (EmojiconEditText) findViewById(R.id.emojicon_edit_text);
        final View rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
        final RelativeLayout rootSend = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_send);
        final ImageView emojiButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emoji_btn);
        final ImageView submitButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);


        // Give the topmost view of your activity layout hierarchy. This will be used to measure soft keyboard height
        final EmojiconsPopup popup = new EmojiconsPopup(rootView, this);


        //Will automatically set size according to the soft keyboard size
        popup.setSizeForSoftKeyboard();


        //Set on emojicon click listener
        popup.setOnEmojiconClickedListener(new EmojiconGridView.OnEmojiconClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
                emojiconEditText.append(emojicon.getEmoji());
            }
        });


        //Set on backspace click listener
        popup.setOnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(new EmojiconsPopup.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v) {
                KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(
                        0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
                emojiconEditText.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        });


        //If the emoji popup is dismissed, change emojiButton to smiley icon
        popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(emojiButton, R.drawable.smiley);
            }
        });


        //If the text keyboard closes, also dismiss the emoji popup
        popup.setOnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(new EmojiconsPopup.OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onKeyboardOpen(int keyBoardHeight) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyboardClose() {
                if(popup.isShowing())
                    popup.dismiss();
            }
        });


        //On emoji clicked, add it to edittext
        popup.setOnEmojiconClickedListener(new EmojiconGridView.OnEmojiconClickedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
                emojiconEditText.append(emojicon.getEmoji());
            }
        });


        //On backspace clicked, emulate the KEYCODE_DEL key event
        popup.setOnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(new EmojiconsPopup.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v) {
                KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(
                        0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
                emojiconEditText.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        });

        // To toggle between text keyboard and emoji keyboard keyboard(Popup)
        emojiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //If popup is not showing => emoji keyboard is not visible, we need to show it
                if(!popup.isShowing()){

                    //If keyboard is visible, simply show the emoji popup
                    if(popup.isKeyBoardOpen()){
                        popup.showAtBottom();
                        changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(emojiButton, R.drawable.ic_action_keyboard);
                    }

                    //else, open the text keyboard first and immediately after that show the emoji popup
                    else{
                        emojiconEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        emojiconEditText.requestFocus();
                        popup.showAtBottomPending();
                        final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(emojiconEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                        changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(emojiButton, R.drawable.ic_action_keyboard);
                    }
                }

                //If popup is showing, simply dismiss it to show the undelying text keyboard
                else{
                    popup.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });


        //On submit, add the edittext text to listview and clear the edittext
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newText = emojiconEditText.getText().toString();

                if(!connectionDetector.isConnectedToInternet())
                    displayConnectionAlert("Cellular Data is Off","Enable your data pockets or wifi");
                else
                {
                    if(!newText.equals("") && newText.trim().length() > 0)
                        send(newText);
                }
                emojiconEditText.getText().clear();
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeEmojiKeyboardIcon(ImageView iconToBeChanged, int drawableResourceId){
        iconToBeChanged.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
    }

    @Override public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loader, Bundle bundle) {
        String[] projection = { DataProvider.KEY_ID, DataProvider.COL_MSG, DataProvider.COL_FROM, DataProvider.COL_TO,  DataProvider.COL_AT};
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
                DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override public void onNewIntent(Intent i)
    {
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

        sender = bundle.getString("sender");
        receiver = bundle.getString("receiver");

        String receiver_name = bundle.getString("receiver_name");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(receiver_name);

        Log.e("SENDER", sender);
        //Log.e("RECEIVER NAME", receiver_name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(menu.findItem(4) == null) {
            menu.add(R.id.main_menu, 4, Menu.NONE, "Shutdown").setIcon(R.drawable.shutdown).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }

        MenuItem contacts = menu.findItem(R.id.action_contacts);
        contacts.setVisible(false);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id) {
            case R.id.action_contacts:
                Intent toContacts = new Intent(this, ContactsActivity.class);
                startActivity(toContacts);
                break;
            case 4:
                DatabaseHandler dbH = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                dbH.deleteMessages();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Messages Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
                break;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                else if(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened())
                    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();

                Intent logout = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(logout);
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void send(final String message)
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                String result = new HttpSender("http://178.62.0.225/sup/public/api/sup/message", "POST")
                        .sendMessage(message, sender, receiver);

                Log.e("MESSAGE RESULT", result);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
                values.put(DataProvider.COL_MSG, message);
                values.put(DataProvider.COL_TO, receiver);
                values.put(DataProvider.COL_AT, new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
                getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, values);

                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    /*@Override public void onStop()
    {
        DatabaseHandler dbH = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        dbH.deleteMessages();
        super.onStop();
    }*/

    @Override public void onDestroy()
    {
        DatabaseHandler dbH = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        dbH.deleteMessages();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint){}

    public class mUpdateClockTask implements Runnable {
        private TextView tv;
        final Handler mClockHandler = new Handler();
        String tag;

        public mUpdateClockTask(TextView tv,String tag) {
            this.tv = tv;
            this.tag = tag;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (tv.getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
                // do what ever you want to happen every second
                int counter_value = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
                if(counter_value > 0)
                {
                    counter_value -= 1;
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter_value));
                }
                else
                {
                    getContentResolver().delete(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(tag)});
                }
                mClockHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: "Every ListView row need to have counter." Why?

Comment: I solved a problem. Because every list item was a self destructing message, and user could select after how many seconds he wants messages to disappear. My solution was to extend TextView and create custom one with timer.